# Convert comma decimals to period decimals with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

As the title indicates, I wish to convert comma decimals (french Canadian system)  to period decimals with VBA.

Other than that,

1. It must convert the 3rd and 4th column
2. Some cells within these columns are empty (I'm not talking about the empty cells below all decimals, but those in between)
3. The decimals are strings
4. The number of rows in the picture below are only for example purposes. They may be much more numerous.
5. The decimals also differ from sheet to sheet (bank statement to bank statement), so I don't want a code only applicable to these numbers.
6. The decimal separator is ","
7. The group separator is " "

Lastly, some images of what I want **NOT exactly** (please read the above beforehand):

From this

[image]

To this

[image]

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried up to now in VBA and what exactly isn't working in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press the "Record a macro" button;
2. Select 3. and 4. column;
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>;
4. Write what you need to be replaced in the fields of the [Replace box](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-0e304ca5-ecef-4808-b90f-fdb42f892e90);
5. Replace;
6. Stop recordning the macro;
7. See the recorded code;

Comment: Probably Ctrl+H

Comment: @BrakNicku - true :)

Comment: I think my question was too broad. There are usually way too many numbers to manually type them. Plus, they also are different (bank statements from different corporations). @vityata I don't think I would've asked the question if it were as easy (many solutions on google), with all due respect.

Comment: In the example you provide, the answer Vityata has given would work. Not only would the process clear up the mess, but you'd have code you can run again to do it again later. Not to mention the vba code basis of a fix that you could modify to suit your needs. If there are reasons or examples of data that would make this ineffective, then add them to your question examples so we can work around them.

Comment: @Sam - I guess you did not understand the proposed solution. The only "manual" part is entering once `,` and `.` in the replace fields.

Comment: @Vityata I indeed didn’t understand your solution but now I do with your clarification. I never thought converting these decimals would be as simple. Thanks!

Comment: @CLR yes, you’re right. I didn’t understand the solution but now i do. Thanks